# URLFetch is unable to fetch the URL

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am trying to fetch the excel file from this url:-

https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate=20220909&assetClassId=3&reportType=P&excluded=CEE,CEU,KCB

But when I am trying to do it using URLFetchApp, script is getting timed out.
Although when I click on this URL directly to open this in browser, file gets download

Code I am using :-

```
 let url  = "https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate=20220909&assetClassId=3&reportType=P&excluded=CEE,CEU,KCB"
   const excelFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
```

Comment: Probably blocked..

Comment: @vector Thank you for replying. About `Thanks, but I wanted it to run automatically, like download those file and update the existing spreadsheet, at certain time in a day, can you help me how I can do that please?` and `For this method, someone has to manually run the function`, I deeply apologize my proposed answer was not useful for your situation. I think that this is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because this method was not useful for your situation. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike thanks for answering it anyway, you're amazing as always, can you guide me please how I can do that, can I use deploy the webapp and call that URL using URLFetch and that Webapp return data? can I do that someway?

Comment: It is highly likely that the request from Google Server is blocked. There is no response for the top page also.